# Where should I put uploaded files on a Clean Architecture project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, clean-architecture

Woudn't be on the Infrastructure Layer? But how could I access this files? Generally, static files would be in `wwwroot`, in Web or Api project, right? Then how could I get this files if they are in another project? Or should I create an assets folder inside Infrastructure project? Or should I access folders on the file system in the server?

Comment: If the files are static mainly then use wwwroot.  All projects in the solution can access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best place to put an upload folder is in the project root:

```bash
 - src
   - <project files> 
 - uploads # put your files here
```